# Clear polystyrene bottle holder repaired with butyl acetate glue. Is it safe to use in the fridge?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've successfully repaired my fridge's bottle holder, which is made of clear polystyrene, using butyl acetate glue.

While the glue smelled at the time I was gluing, the repaired bottle holder no longer smells.  The couple drops of glue which ran now appear to be made of solid polystyrene.  They and are not liquid or sticky.

Are there any health and safety reasons which should stop me from using the repaired bottle holder in the fridge?  (There is often uncovered food in the fridge, but no unpackaged food in direct contact with the repaired bottle holder.)

Comment: Acetate? It was acrylate, wasn't it? Likely this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyl_cyanoacrylate

Comment: @Mithoron The glue's paper insert reads: "Warning Humbrol Polycement contains butyl acetate" and doesn't mention any other chemicals.  https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B000JCE690  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butyl_acetate  (If you're the down-voter, would you mind removing it?)

Comment: Butyl acetate is just a solvent, and if the thing doesn't have its smell, its volatility shouldn't be a problem now.

Comment: You should edit it with details and better wording, like "glue *containing* butyl acetate". Still, questions like that are kinda problematic. Borderline "personal medical" thing. How do we know if someone isn't for example allergic, or glue got spoiled, or whatever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Butyl acetate](https://www.cosmeticsinfo.org/ingredients/butyl-acetate/) is found in small quantity in fruits such as apples, and is considered safe, in most regions, for use in nail polish.

However, this site specifically excludes medical recommendations. (Personally, I would not recommend eating the plastic bottle holder, even if you enjoy the solvent odor ;-)